# Good pattern for redux action in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Supposing I have an `update comment` action. When a user updates comment after getting a successful result from `Promise` I should close comment editor. This is my sample code from my project:

```
export const updateComment = (comment,callBack/* ? */) => {
   return (dispatch, getState){
      api.updateComment({...comment}).then((result) => {
             /* Do something */
             callback() /* ? */
       })
    }
}
```

In `react component` I use action like the following code:

```
handleUpdateComment(){
  dispatch(actions.updateComment(this.state.comment,this.closeCommentEitor)
}
```

It works well but I think is not a good pattern to close comment editor. I'm looking a correct pattern to close editor without passing `callBack` like I did if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `redux-thunk`, you can `dispatch` an action from another action.
What you can do is that, `commentEditor` have a state which you store in redux and based on that state open or close the `commentEditor`

```
export const updateComment = (comment, comment_id) => {
   return (dispatch, getState){
      api.updateComment({...comment}).then((result) => {
             /* Do something */
             dispatch({type: 'CLOSE_COMMENT_EDITOR', id: comment_id})
       })
    }
}
```

After this in a reducer on this action change the state of redux store, something like

```
import update from 'immutability-helper'


var initialState = [{commentId: '1', commentEditorOpenStatus: false}, {commentId: '2', commentEditorOpenStatus: false}]
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch(action.type) {
         'CLOSE_COMMENT_EDITOR': 
                  const idx = state.findIndex(obj => obj.commentId == action.id);
                  return update(state, {
                         [idx]: {
                              commentEditorOpenStatus: {
                                  $set: false
                               }
                          }
                   })
            // Other action handlers here
            default: return state
     }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I intend to do it but the problem is that maybe there are many comments open so I should say the comment editor with that `id` of comment should be closed. I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: In that case pass the API with comment and comment_id, with that you can dispatch an action with payload as comment_id and then toggle the state in reducer based on id

Comment: Can I have a reference to figure out utterly?

Comment: I don't have any reference to some docs currently but added  a way to handle this in your reducer

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing that updates your application's state is your reducers.

The reducer should be responsible to update the state of your application and not your action (you are now passing getState).

I suggest you to look at [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware)

The middleware enables optimistic updates and dispatches pending, fulfilled and rejected actions, which can be intercepted by the reducer.